# Make conditional inside Jade loop

Tags: node.js, pug

I'am trying to add conditional inside Jade `each` loop. But I've got an error `Unexpected token (4:28)`. Is it possible to implement such behavior with Jade native syntax?

```
- var sizes = ['L', 'default', 'S']
each size in sizes
  if (size == 'default')
    button(class="s-btn s-btn--brand") Default
  else 
    button(class="s-btn s-btn--brand s-btn--#{size}") Size
```

Also, I've tried to implement with JS support inside Jade, but it also fails with same error.

```
-
  for(i=0; i<sizes.length;i++){
    var size = sizes[i];
    if(size=='default'){
      button(class="s-btn s-btn--brand") Default    
    }
    else {
      button(class="s-btn s-btn--brand s-btn--#{size}") Size
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. Add comma between 'default' and 'S'